# System.out.println doesn't print in Windows Linux Subsystem bash

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, stdout, stderr, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a very simple **Hello World** java program that just prints a line using `System.out.println`:

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");
    }
}
```

When I execute this code in a Windows terminal or a native Linux terminal it works fine, when I try to execute it in the Ubuntu bash of the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) it's not showing anything. If instead I use `System.err.println` it prints the line. I didn't have similar problems with Python.

My java version is:

```
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. First, I'd suggest ensuring you're running Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (or later). Then make sure you've applied all the latest updates to your distro (assuming Ubuntu: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Then you should be able to do this:

[image]